# LINQ how to get N number of rows form table starting from K index?

Tags: c#, database, linq, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

like in the topic I need get further rows from my sqlite database using linq and merge them with my observableCollection. I have to start at some index and get for example 100 next rows when user is scrolling to the bottom of the list.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Skip` and `Take`:

```
{query}.Skip(index).Take(100);
```

Note that this assumes a 0-based index (0 is the first record).

Comment: you should also make sure that your {query} is ordered, so you always get the same partition with the same arguments

Comment: Yes my query is ordered by ID and it looks like that: 
var query = db.Table<Towar>().OrderBy(c => c.Id).Skip(index).Take(100);
Thanks guys for help!